# Combining common values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Say for Instance I have the following table (full of connections between members)

```
connectionA    ConnectionB
   887             225
   129             887
   225             887
   887             562
   562             887
```

How am I able to use SQL to find all of the rows where both A is connected to B and vice versa. The query would return (no duplications allowed):

```
connectionA    ConnectionB
   887             225
   887             562
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT T1.connectionA, T1.connectionB
FROM yourtable T1
JOIN yourtable T2
ON T1.connectionA = T2.connectionB
AND T2.connectionA = T1.connectionB
WHERE T1.connectionA > T1.connectionB
```